# remove those tuples having duplicate elements in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

```
n,k = map(int,input().split())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
l=[]
for i in range(k):
    l.append(list(itertools.combinations(a,i+1)))
print(l)
```

output:

```
l =[[()],[(2,), (2,), (3,), (3,), (5,)], [(2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 3), (2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 3), (3, 5), (3, 5)], [(2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 5), (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 5), (3, 3, 5)]]
```

**Problem Statement :-**
You are given a sequence of prime numbers A1,A2,…,AN. This sequence has exactly 2^N subsequences. subsequence of A is good if it does not contain any two identical numbers; in particular, the empty sequence is good.find the number of good subsequences which contain at most K numbers.

**Example :-**
INPUT : 5 3 (N=5, K=3)
        2 2 3 3 5

There is 1 good subsequence with length 0 (i.e. empty case), 5 good subsequences with length 1 (i.e. {2,2,3,3,5}), 8 good subsequences with length 2 and 4 good subsequences with length 3.

OUTPUT : 18 (1+5+8+4)

Sample Code is attached above but its complexity is very high. I want to make it efficient.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are exactly asking. Neither what you mean with "answer should be 18"

Comment: It's a problem in an ongoing challenge [link](https://www.codechef.com/SEPT19B/problems/GDSUB).

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
import sys
import numpy as np

mod = 1000000007

n, k = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
a = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))

fre = [0]*10000
A = []
for i in range(0, n):
    fre[a[i]] += 1
for i in range(0, 8001):
    if fre[i] > 0:
        A.append(fre[i])   
kk = min( len( A ), k ) + 1
S = np.zeros( kk, dtype=int );   S[0] = 1
for a in A:
   S[1:kk] = (S[1:kk] + (a * S[0:kk-1])% mod) % mod
ans = 0
for s in S:
    ans = ((ans + s) % mod)
print(ans)
```